# I want that whenever I press SPACE, a new pygame window will pop up. But the program is showing some errors whenever i press SPACE

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, pygame.font, pygame.event, pygame.draw, string
from pygame.locals import *

counter = 0


def get_key():
    global counter
    while 1:
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            return event.key
        else:
            pass


def display_box(screen, message):
    global counter
    "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
    fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None, 18)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255),
                     ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                      (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                      200, 20), 1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0),
                     ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                      (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                      204, 24), 1)
    if len(message) != 0:
        screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255, 255, 255)),
                    ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
    pygame.display.flip()


def ask(screen):
    global counter
    str_counter = str(counter)
    "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
    pygame.font.init()
    current_string = []
    display_box(screen, "comment" + ": " + string.join(current_string, ""))
    while 1:
        inkey = get_key()
        if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
            current_string = current_string[0:-1]
        elif inkey == K_RETURN:
            break
        elif inkey == K_SPACE:

            screen = screen + str_counter
            counter = counter + 1

        elif inkey <= 127:
            current_string.append(chr(inkey))
        display_box(screen, "comment" + ": " + string.join(current_string, ""))
    return string.join(current_string, "")


def main():
    global counter
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 100))
    print ask(screen)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you press Space? It'd be useful to add that to your post so that people can help you with your problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/PycharmProjects/Screenshots/tesssst.py", line 62, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/home/rahul/PycharmProjects/Screenshots/tesssst.py", line 60, in main
    print ask(screen)
  File "/home/rahul/PycharmProjects/Screenshots/tesssst.py", line 49, in ask
    screen = screen+str_counter
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pygame.Surface' and 'str'

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you try to "add" a screen (pygame.Surface) and counter (string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is cause in line 49 you are performing the operation screen = screen + str_counter, which is attempting to add a pygame.Surface object and a string object, which can not be added together.

In addition, pygames is not regularly built to be able to handle running multiple windows at the same time. If you want to have multiple windows running in pygames you will need to use multiprocessing or other modules that can run multiple windows such as pyglet or cocos2d.